# Django Filter Error

Tags: python, django

I want to save and filter users objects in my django app. After inputting the below codes, the imagefield keeps giving me a validation error, saying:

```
                         This field is required.
```

It’s pointing to the imagefield that I should fill it. How can I get rid of that error and make it filter?

Models

```
      class Fin(models.Model):
         user=models.ForeignKey(User)
         title=models.CharField(max_length=250)
         main_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos")
         side_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos")
         address=models.CharField(max_length=200)
         city=models.CharField(max_length=200)
         state=models.CharField(max_length=200)
         guideline=models.TextField(max_length=1000)

         def __unicode__(self):
              return self.title

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return self.title

    class FinForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
           model=Fin
           fields=('title','main_view','side_view', 'address','city','state','guideline')
           exclude=('user')
```

Views

```
        def fincrib(request):
            extra_data_context={}
             #if there's nothing in the field do nothing.
            if request. method=="POST":
               form =FinForm(request.POST)
               if form.is_valid():
                  data=form.cleaned_data
                  newfincribs=Fin(
                     user= request.user,
                     title=data['title'],
                     main_view=Fin.objects.latest['main_view'],
                     side_view=Fin.objects.latest['side_view'],
                     address=data['address'],
                     city=data['city'],
                     state=data['state'],
                     guideline=data['guideline'])
                 newfincribs.save()
              extra_data_context.update({'FinForm':form})
        else:
            form = FinForm()
            extra_data_context.update({'FinForm':form})
        extra_data_context.update({'Fins':Fin.objects.filter(user=request.user)})

        plan=Fin.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        paginator=Paginator(plan, 5)

        try:
          page=request.GET.get('page', '1')
        except ValueError:
          page=1

        try:
          Fins=paginator.page(page)
        except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
          Fins=paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
       extra_data_context.update({'Fins': Fins})
       return render_to_response('post.html',extra_data_context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template

```
        {% block content %}
          <form action="." method="POST">
               {% csrf_token %}
       <center> {{FinForm.as_p}}  </center>
           <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
           </form>


          {% for Fin in Fins.object_list %}
           <tr>
            <a href="{% url profiles_edit_profile %}"> {{Fin.user}} </a> </p> </strong>
             <p>{{Fin.title}}</p>
             <p><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{Fin.main_view}}"/></p>
             <p> <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{Fin.side_view}}"/></p>
             <p> {{Fin.address}} </p>
             <p> {{Fin.city}}</p>
              <p> {{Fin.state}}</p>
              <p> {{Fin.guideline}}</p>
            {% endfor %}

     <div class="pagination">
       <span class="step-links">
           {% if Fins.has_previous %}
              <a href="?page={{ Fins.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
           {% endif %}

    <span class="current">
      Page {{ Fins.number }} of {{ Fins.paginator.num_pages }}
    </span>

         {% if Fins.has_next %}
             <a href="?page={{ Fins.next_page_number }}">next</a>
         {% endif %}
       </span>
      </div>
     {% endblock %}
```

Comment: did u log request.POST dict. what are you getting?

Comment: try adding blank=True and save..lets see what data gets stored in the table

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**change**

```
main_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos")
side_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos")
```

**to**

```
main_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos", blank=True, null=True)
side_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos", blank=True, null=True)
```

btw, im not sure which django version you're using but your code is rather messy, any reason you're not using CBVs and static tags?

Comment: because after syncing the database for the first time, django defined your columns in the database as NOT NULL, so either you delete the table and sync again, or you modify the schema by yourself

Comment: After changing it, I'm getting this error:TypeError at /crip/ 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'getitem' I'm using Django 1.4 and Python 2.7.3 –

Answer (score 0):

It's because by default all model fields are required, it means if you want to create and save new model instance in the database, you should fill all the mandatory fields. Maybe

```
main_view=Fin.objects.latest['main_view'],
side_view=Fin.objects.latest['side_view'],
```

is giving you the error, because there is no data.